# Error of "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'" shown after upgraded Xcode

Tags: swift, subscript, ios9.3

After I upgrade my Xcode to the latest version. It shows this error. Not sure what it means.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ambiguous` error occurs when the type of the object is `AnyObject` and the compiler has no idea whether the object can be key subscripted.

The solution is to cast `result` down to something suitable.
It seems to be a dictionary

```
if let dict = result as? [String:AnyObject] {
   let userId = dict["id"] as! String
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `result` type, for example if this is a Dictionary try:

```
let dic: NSDictionary = result
let userId: String = dic["id"] as! String
```